# Proof that the probability of the union of pairwise disjoints events is equal to the sum of probabilities of all events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I used induction for the proof, but I am not sure if the beginning and final steps are clear. Specifically, the part that explain I need to use $n=2$ as the base case and the last step.

Let $(S,P)$ be a sample space and suppose that $E_1, E_2, \ldots, E_n$ are pairwise disjoint events. Prove that

$P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup .. \cup E_n) = P(E_1)+P(E_2)+\dots+P(E_n)$.

**Proof:**
We are given a sample space (S,P) where $E_1, E_2, \ldots, E_n$ are pairwise disjoint events. We seek to prove the above statement by mathematical principle of induction.

First, we establish a base case where $n = 1$.

$P(E_1)= P(E_1)$

Therefore, the statement is true for $n = 1$. Since the statement equates the probabilities of union of multiple items to the sum of their probabilities, for the base case, we will also have to show that it is true for more than 1 item, $n = 2$.

By the definition of union, we get
$P(E_1 \cup E_2) = P(E_1) + P(E_2) - P(E_1 \cap E_2)$

Since all the events are pairwise disjoint, $P(E_1 \cap E_2) = 0$. Therefore, $P(E_1 \cup E_2) = P(E_1) + P(E_2)$.

Next, we introduce the induction hypothesis that the statement is true for $n = x$ where $x$ is some positive integer greater than $2$. So we get the following: $$P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup \ldots \cup E_x) = P(E_1)+P(E_2)+\dots+P(E_x)$$

Then, for the inductive step, we need to show that the statement is true where $n = x + 1$.

Since $P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup \ldots \cup E_x) = P(E_1)+P(E_2)+\dots+P(E_x)$, we add $P(E_{x+1})$ to both sides of the equation:

$$P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup \ldots \cup E_x) + P(E_{x+1}) = P(E_1)+P(E_2)+\dots+P(E_x) + P(E_{x+1})$$

We let $P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup \ldots \cup E_x) = P(A)$ and from the hypothesis we know that $P(E_1)+P(E_2)+\dots+P(E_x)=P(A)$, hence we get:

$$P(A) + P(E_{x+1}) = P(A) + P(E_{x+1})$$

Since all the events in the sample space are pairwise disjoint, $P(A)$, the union of events $E_1, E_2, \ldots , E_x$, will be a disjoint to $P(E_{x+1})$. It is because no element in the union $E_1, E_2, \ldots , E_x$ will share the same element with $E_{x+1}$.

Therefore $P(A \cap E_{x+1}) = 0$.

$$P(A \cup E_{x+1}) = P(A) + P(E_{x+1}) - P(A \cap E_{x+1})$$

Hence,

$$P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup \dots \cup E_x \cup E_{x+1}) = P(E_1)+P(E_2)+\dots+P(E_x) + P(E_{x+1})$$

Therefore, the statement is true for $n = x + 1$

By the principle of mathematical induction, we have proven that $P(E_1 \cup E_2 \cup \dots \cup E_n) = P(E_1)+P(E_2)+\dots+P(E_n)$.

Comment: It is ok your induction, you could start with $n=2$ since the property is for finite disjoints events. But htere is an easy way to prove that using $P(\varnothing)=0$ and 3th Kolomogorov's Axiom for probability